# Is it possible to migrate or restore deleted posts?

Tags: discussion, support

I was sad when I discovered that one of the posts I favorited was deleted... if you can see deleted posts, here is a link: [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered)

I haven't read through them all, so on days when I'm bored or need a laugh, I skim through it.

So now that it's been deleted, is there a way to restore it, out of prosperity, or maybe migrate it somewhere else? It's fine that it's locked, but some days we all need a chuckle!

Comment: It isn't official but there's an archived copy [here](http://www.stackprinter.com/questions/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered.html), along with copies of [many other deleted questions](http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have created a new bookmark :)

Comment: I just found the same today. Beside I know it was deleted for a reason, I don't see why this question is downvoted. Some question just stay as "For historical reasons this question (bla bla bla) but is not encouraged...".

Comment: Thank you so much for the link!  I was so sad that I couldn't share this gem with other engineers that don't yet know the kind of experiences a software developer can go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's technically possible. But why would it be done? The post was deleted for a reason.

[StackPrinter archives some of the popular deleted questions.](http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted) Including [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](http://www.stackprinter.com/questions/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered.html)

Comment: Thanks, I did not even know that StackPrinter existed.

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely possible for it to be undeleted and migrated, but what site would it go on? It's not a good fit for any site in the network, since it doesn't actually try to solve a problem. Posts that give people a "chuckle" are the definition of "[chatty, open-ended questions [that] diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)"

Comment: Before anyone suggests it, **not Programmers**. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @MarkTrapp Your profile message rulez! +1

Comment: Yes, thank you, I know what the FAQ page says